# I'm making a drawing based web-app and I'm using HTML Canvas to handle the drawing, however the drawing is offset to the right a lot?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
const map = document.getElementById('map')
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
const grid = document.getElementById('grid')
function resize() {
    canvas.width = map.offsetWidth
    canvas.height = map.offsetHeight

    ctx.width = map.offsetWidth
    ctx.height = map.offsetHeight
}
resize();
grid.appendChild(canvas)
canvas.style.gridColumn = 2
canvas.style.gridRow = 1



let pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition);

function setPosition(e) {
    pos.x = e.clientX;
    pos.y = e.clientY;
}



  function draw(e) {
    if (e.buttons !== 1) return;
  
    ctx.beginPath();
  
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#c0392b';
  
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    setPosition(e);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
  
    ctx.stroke();
  }
```

Heres the code that generates the canvas relative to the size of a picture and allows the user to draw on the canvas. I've looked over another StackOverflow post with the same problem but no relevant answers. I know that the cause of the problem is that the canvas is stretched from it's standard proportion of 300 x 150 and is drawing at the correct position mathematically but not physically. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you post full code? Above example is missing map variable.

Comment: Please, post what you are trying to achieve , I noticed you have written that drawing is offset to right a lot , but that doesn't answer what you are trying to fix